AHKV1: If I have a list of window titles, how do I then determine the Z order just for these windows?
Lets say that of the windows that exist on my system, the following is a subset of them:

Untitled - Notepad
ShareX 15.0
Settings
Calculator
my blog - Firefox
Everything 1.5.0.1363a (x64)

and I just so happen to have an array of this list:
windowTitles := ["Untitled - Notepad", "ShareX 15.0", "Settings", "Calculator", "my blog - Firefox", "Everything 1.5.0.1363a (x64)"]

These windows as they exist on my system have, their own place in the "Z order", how can I then determine what the Z order for a window in the windowTitles array is?
For example if I wanted to activate the most recently active window in windowTitles, how would I do that?
ahk_group is what first came to mind but it does not fit the bill. I need to be able to query the list (windowTitles) and then determine the windows Z order.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

WinActivate % windowTitles[1] activates the first window in that array.
